# Google Maps API Geocode - return GPS coordinations

Tags: google-maps, geocode

I've got this code:

```
var get_lat = function(address) {
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            console.log('lat is: '+ results[0].geometry.location.lat());
            return results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        }
    });
}

var get_lng = function(address) {
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            console.log('lng is: '+ results[0].geometry.location.lng());
            return results[0].geometry.location.lng();
        }
    });
}
```

In console it prints the coordinates I need, but the return value is always undefined:

I use it in classic initialize for Google Maps like this:

```
function createMarker(latlng) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
    });
}

function initialize() {
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(49.210366,15.989588)
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    var address = "Correct address that console.logs the correct GPS coordinations in function definitions above";
    var gps_lat = get_lat(address);
    var gps_lng = get_lng(address);
    console.log('GPS lat: ' + gps_lat); // logs "undefined"
    console.log('GPS lng: ' + gps_lng); // logs "undefined"

    var marker = createMarker({lat: gps_lat}, lng: gps_lng});
}


$(window).on("load", function (e) {  
    initialize();
});
```

Do you have any idea why the function consoles the right value but it doesn't return anything?

For GMAP API I use this script: http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=geometry

Answer (score 1):

You have the `return` inside an anonymous function that you pass to `geocoder.geocode`, all in yet another function (`get_lat`/`get_lng`). `get_lat`/`get_lng` themselves don't have a `return` statement, and thus return `undefined`.

Furthermore, `geocoder.geocode` will call your anonymous function asynchronously. Which means that there is no chance for `get_lat`/`get_lng` to get hold of the `return` value and `return` it where `get_lat`/`get_lng` was called.

One solution (the simplest one) is to put the `createMarker` code in the callback for `geocoder.geocode`. Also, in this case you will have to merge your two `get_lat`/`get_lng` functions. Example:

```
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var gps_lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat()
        var gps_lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
        console.log('lat is ' + gps_lat + '. lng is ' + gps_lng);
        var marker = createMarker({lat: gps_lat, lng: gps_lng});
        return results[0].geometry.location.lat();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait until Google API gives response. So write a logic to create marker in **callback function** of Google API as shown below.

```
var getLatLng = function (address)
    {
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status)
        {                
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
            {
                var location = results[0].geometry.location;

                // Create marker once you get response from Google
                createMarker({ lat: location.lat(), lng: location.lng() });
            }
        });
    }
```

and call that function as shown below

```
function initialize()
    {
        var myOptions =
        {
            zoom: 8,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(49.210366, 15.989588)
        }

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
        var address = "Correct address that console.logs the correct GPS coordinations in function definitions above";            

        // Old code ------------------------------------------------
        //var gps_lat = get_lat(address);
        //var gps_lng = get_lng(address);

        //console.log('GPS lat: ' + gps_lat); // logs "undefined"
        //console.log('GPS lng: ' + gps_lng); // logs "undefined"

        //var marker = createMarker({ lat: gps_lat, lng: gps_lng });
        // ----------------------------------------------------------

        // New code
        getLatLng(address);
    }
```

and you will get marker on a map